# My WordPress page is bugging after migration

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I recently changed my site's host provider, and in the process I also changed my domain name. `www.vægbyg.dk` -> `www.vaegbyg.dk`

I downloaded/uploaded my database through "phpMyAdmin", and used FileZilla to transfer all my files. I changed my config file to match my new database. I changed the site URL, and home in WP_OPTIONS.

My "old" `.htaccess` seems to cause a problem. When I have it in the `public_html` folder I get this error:

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>   Please contact the server administrator at [no address was given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

If I then delete the `.htaccess` file, when I access my website `www.vaegbyg.dk`, it automatically redirects to my old domain `www.vægbyg.dk`. If I then try to access `mysite.com/wp-login.php`, or `mysite.com/wp-admin`, I get an error saying "too many redirects occurring".

How do I complete this migration so that my new site is accessed via the new domain name?

---

> **Added 2017-11-28 20:26:38Z**

Great. I still have the issue with my .htaccess file though. If I go to setting>permalinks>Save Changes. To establish my new .htaccess file the site crashes until I delete the .htaccess file, which contains "

```
# BEGIN WordPress
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70s .php
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 6 hours"
</IfModule>
Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "2"
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The file I get when the new .htaccess file is installed says

```
<?php
/**
 * Permalink Settings Administration Screen.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Administration
 */

/** WordPress Administration Bootstrap */
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/admin.php' );

if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
    wp_die( __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to manage options for this site.' ) );

$title = __('Permalink Settings');
$parent_file = 'options-general.php';

get_current_screen()->add_help_tab( array(
    'id'      => 'overview',
    'title'   => __('Overview'),
    'content' => '<p>' . __('Permalinks are the permanent URLs to your individual pages and blog posts, as well as your category and tag archives. A permalink is the web address used to link to your content. The URL to each post should be permanent, and never change &#8212; hence the name permalink.') . '</p>' .
        '<p>' . __( 'This screen allows you to choose your permalink structure. You can choose from common settings or create custom URL structures.' ) . '</p>' .
        '<p>' . __('You must click the Save Changes button at the bottom of the screen for new settings to take effect.') . '</p>',
) );

get_current_screen()->add_help_tab( array(
    'id'      => 'permalink-settings',
    'title'   => __('Permalink Settings'),
    'content' => '<p>' . __( 'Permalinks can contain useful information, such as the post date, title, or other elements. You can choose from any of the suggested permalink formats, or you can craft your own if you select Custom Structure.' ) . '</p>' .
        '<p>' . __( 'If you pick an option other than Plain, your general URL path with structure tags (terms surrounded by <code>%</code>) will also appear in the custom structure field and your path can be further modified there.' ) . '</p>' .
        '<p>' . __('When you assign multiple categories or tags to a post, only one can show up in the permalink: the lowest numbered category. This applies if your custom structure includes <code>%category%</code> or <code>%tag%</code>.') . '</p>' .
        '<p>' . __('You must click the Save Changes button at the bottom of the screen for new settings to take effect.') . '</p>',
) );

get_current_screen()->add_help_tab( array(
    'id'      => 'custom-structures',
    'title'   => __('Custom Structures'),
    'content' => '<p>' . __('The Optional fields let you customize the &#8220;category&#8221; and &#8220;tag&#8221; base names that will appear in archive URLs. For example, the page listing all posts in the &#8220;Uncategorized&#8221; category could be <code>/topics/uncategorized</code> instead of <code>/category/uncategorized</code>.') . '</p>' .
        '<p>' . __('You must click the Save Changes button at the bottom of the screen for new settings to take effect.') . '</p>',
) );

get_current_screen()->set_help_sidebar(
    '<p><strong>' . __('For more information:') . '</strong></p>' .
    '<p>' . __('<a href="https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen">Documentation on Permalinks Settings</a>') . '</p>' .
    '<p>' . __('<a href="https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks">Documentation on Using Permalinks</a>') . '</p>' .
    '<p>' . __('<a href="https://wordpress.org/support/">Support Forums</a>') . '</p>'
);

$home_path = get_home_path();
$iis7_permalinks = iis7_supports_permalinks();
$permalink_structure = get_option( 'permalink_structure' );

$prefix = $blog_prefix = '';
if ( ! got_url_rewrite() )
    $prefix = '/index.php';

/**
 * In a subdirectory configuration of multisite, the `/blog` prefix is used by
 * default on the main site to avoid collisions with other sites created on that
 * network. If the `permalink_structure` option has been changed to remove this
 * base prefix, WordPress core can no longer account for the possible collision.
 */
if ( is_multisite() && ! is_subdomain_install() && is_main_site() && 0 === strpos( $permalink_structure, '/blog/' ) ) {
    $blog_prefix = '/blog';
}

$category_base       = get_option( 'category_base' );
$tag_base            = get_option( 'tag_base' );
$update_required     = false;

if ( $iis7_permalinks ) {
    if ( ( ! file_exists($home_path . 'web.config') && win_is_writable($home_path) ) || win_is_writable($home_path . 'web.config') )
        $writable = true;
    else
        $writable = false;
} elseif ( $is_nginx ) {
    $writable = false;
} else {
    if ( ( ! file_exists( $home_path . '.htaccess' ) && is_writable( $home_path ) ) || is_writable( $home_path . '.htaccess' ) ) {
        $writable = true;
    } else {
        $writable = false;
        $existing_rules  = array_filter( extract_from_markers( $home_path . '.htaccess', 'WordPress' ) );
        $new_rules       = array_filter( explode( "\n", $wp_rewrite->mod_rewrite_rules() ) );
        $update_required = ( $new_rules !== $existing_rules );
    }
}

$using_index_permalinks = $wp_rewrite->using_index_permalinks();

if ( isset($_POST['permalink_structure']) || isset($_POST['category_base']) ) {
    check_admin_referer('update-permalink');

    if ( isset( $_POST['permalink_structure'] ) ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['selection'] ) && 'custom' != $_POST['selection'] )
            $permalink_structure = $_POST['selection'];
        else
            $permalink_structure = $_POST['permalink_structure'];

        if ( ! empty( $permalink_structure ) ) {
            $permalink_structure = preg_replace( '#/+#', '/', '/' . str_replace( '#', '', $permalink_structure ) );
            if ( $prefix && $blog_prefix )
                $permalink_structure = $prefix . preg_replace( '#^/?index\.php#', '', $permalink_structure );
            else
                $permalink_structure = $blog_prefix . $permalink_structure;
        }

        $permalink_structure = sanitize_option( 'permalink_structure', $permalink_structure );

        $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( $permalink_structure );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['category_base'] ) ) {
        $category_base = $_POST['category_base'];
        if ( ! empty( $category_base ) )
            $category_base = $blog_prefix . preg_replace('#/+#', '/', '/' . str_replace( '#', '', $category_base ) );
        $wp_rewrite->set_category_base( $category_base );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['tag_base'] ) ) {
        $tag_base = $_POST['tag_base'];
        if ( ! empty( $tag_base ) )
            $tag_base = $blog_prefix . preg_replace('#/+#', '/', '/' . str_replace( '#', '', $tag_base ) );
        $wp_rewrite->set_tag_base( $tag_base );
    }

    $message = __( 'Permalink structure updated.' );

    if ( $iis7_permalinks ) {
        if ( $permalink_structure && ! $using_index_permalinks && ! $writable ) {
            $message = __( 'You should update your web.config now.' );
        } elseif ( $permalink_structure && ! $using_index_permalinks && $writable ) {
            $message = __( 'Permalink structure updated. Remove write access on web.config file now!' );
        }
    } elseif ( ! $is_nginx && $permalink_structure && ! $using_index_permalinks && ! $writable && $update_required ) {
        $message = __( 'You should update your .htaccess now.' );
    }

    if ( ! get_settings_errors() ) {
        add_settings_error( 'general', 'settings_updated', $message, 'updated' );
    }

    set_transient( 'settings_errors', get_settings_errors(), 30 );

    wp_redirect( admin_url( 'options-permalink.php?settings-updated=true' ) );
    exit;
}

flush_rewrite_rules();

require( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-header.php' );
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h1><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></h1>

<form name="form" action="options-permalink.php" method="post">
<?php wp_nonce_field('update-permalink') ?>

    <p><?php
        printf(
            /* translators: %s: Codex URL */
            __( 'WordPress offers you the ability to create a custom URL structure for your permalinks and archives. Custom URL structures can improve the aesthetics, usability, and forward-compatibility of your links. A <a href="%s">number of tags are available</a>, and here are some examples to get you started.' ),
            __( 'https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks' )
        );
    ?></p>

<?php
if ( is_multisite() && ! is_subdomain_install() && is_main_site() && 0 === strpos( $permalink_structure, '/blog/' ) ) {
    $permalink_structure = preg_replace( '|^/?blog|', '', $permalink_structure );
    $category_base = preg_replace( '|^/?blog|', '', $category_base );
    $tag_base = preg_replace( '|^/?blog|', '', $tag_base );
}

$structures = array(
    0 => '',
    1 => $prefix . '/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/',
    2 => $prefix . '/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/',
    3 => $prefix . '/' . _x( 'archives', 'sample permalink base' ) . '/%post_id%',
    4 => $prefix . '/%postname%/',
);
?>
<h2 class="title"><?php _e('Common Settings'); ?></h2>
<table class="form-table permalink-structure">
    <tr>
        <th><label><input name="selection" type="radio" value="" <?php checked('', $permalink_structure); ?> /> <?php _e( 'Plain' ); ?></label></th>
        <td><code><?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/?p=123</code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label><input name="selection" type="radio" value="<?php echo esc_attr($structures[1]); ?>" <?php checked($structures[1], $permalink_structure); ?> /> <?php _e('Day and name'); ?></label></th>
        <td><code><?php echo get_option('home') . $blog_prefix . $prefix . '/' . date('Y') . '/' . date('m') . '/' . date('d') . '/' . _x( 'sample-post', 'sample permalink structure' ) . '/'; ?></code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label><input name="selection" type="radio" value="<?php echo esc_attr($structures[2]); ?>" <?php checked($structures[2], $permalink_structure); ?> /> <?php _e('Month and name'); ?></label></th>
        <td><code><?php echo get_option('home') . $blog_prefix . $prefix . '/' . date('Y') . '/' . date('m') . '/' . _x( 'sample-post', 'sample permalink structure' ) . '/'; ?></code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label><input name="selection" type="radio" value="<?php echo esc_attr($structures[3]); ?>" <?php checked($structures[3], $permalink_structure); ?> /> <?php _e('Numeric'); ?></label></th>
        <td><code><?php echo get_option('home') . $blog_prefix . $prefix . '/' . _x( 'archives', 'sample permalink base' ) . '/123'; ?></code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label><input name="selection" type="radio" value="<?php echo esc_attr($structures[4]); ?>" <?php checked($structures[4], $permalink_structure); ?> /> <?php _e('Post name'); ?></label></th>
        <td><code><?php echo get_option('home') . $blog_prefix . $prefix . '/' . _x( 'sample-post', 'sample permalink structure' ) . '/'; ?></code></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label><input name="selection" id="custom_selection" type="radio" value="custom" <?php checked( !in_array($permalink_structure, $structures) ); ?> />
            <?php _e('Custom Structure'); ?>
            </label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <code><?php echo get_option('home') . $blog_prefix; ?></code>
            <input name="permalink_structure" id="permalink_structure" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($permalink_structure); ?>" class="regular-text code" />
            <div class="available-structure-tags hide-if-no-js">
                <div id="custom_selection_updated" aria-live="assertive" class="screen-reader-text"></div>
                <?php
                $available_tags = array(
                    /* translators: %s: permalink structure tag */
                    'year'     => __( '%s (The year of the post, four digits, for example 2004.)' ),
                    /* translators: %s: permalink structure tag */
                    'monthnum' => __( '%s (Month of the year, for example 05.)' ),
                    /* translators: %s: permalink structure tag */
                    'day'      => __( '%s (Day of the month, for example 28.)' ),
                    /* translators: %s: permalink structure tag */
                    'hour'     => __( '%s (Hour of the day, for example 15.)' ),
                    /* translators: %s: permalink structure tag */
                    'minute'   => __( '%s (Minute of the hour, for example 43.)' ),
                    /* translators: %s: permalink structure tag */
                    'second'   => __( '%s (Second of the minute, for example 33.)' ),
                    /* translators: %s: permalink structure tag */
                    'post_id'  => __( '%s (The unique ID of the post, for example 423.)' ),
                    /* translators: %s: permalink structure tag */
                    'postname' => __( '%s (The sanitized post title (slug).)' ),
                    /* translators: %s: permalink structure tag */
                    'category' => __( '%s (Category slug. Nested sub-categories appear as nested directories in the URL.)' ),
                    /* translators: %s: permalink structure tag */
                    'author'   => __( '%s (A sanitized version of the author name.)' ),
                );

                /**
                 * Filters the list of available permalink structure tags on the Permalinks settings page.
                 *
                 * @since 4.8.0
                 *
                 * @param array $available_tags A key => value pair of available permalink structure tags.
                 */
                $available_tags = apply_filters( 'available_permalink_structure_tags', $available_tags );

                /* translators: %s: permalink structure tag */
                $structure_tag_added = __( '%s added to permalink structure' );

                /* translators: %s: permalink structure tag */
                $structure_tag_already_used = __( '%s (already used in permalink structure)' );

                if ( ! empty( $available_tags ) ) :
                    ?>
                    <p><?php _e( 'Available tags:' ); ?></p>
                    <ul role="list">
                        <?php
                        foreach ( $available_tags as $tag => $explanation ) {
                            ?>
                            <li>
                                <button type="button"
                                        class="button button-secondary"
                                        aria-label="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( $explanation, $tag ) ); ?>"
                                        data-added="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( $structure_tag_added, $tag ) ); ?>"
                                        data-used="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( $structure_tag_already_used, $tag ) ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo '%' . $tag . '%'; ?>
                                </button>
                            </li>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h2 class="title"><?php _e('Optional'); ?></h2>
<p><?php
/* translators: %s: placeholder that must come at the start of the URL */
printf( __( 'If you like, you may enter custom structures for your category and tag URLs here. For example, using <code>topics</code> as your category base would make your category links like <code>%s/topics/uncategorized/</code>. If you leave these blank the defaults will be used.' ), get_option( 'home' ) . $blog_prefix . $prefix ); ?></p>

<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="category_base"><?php /* translators: prefix for category permalinks */ _e('Category base'); ?></label></th>
        <td><?php echo $blog_prefix; ?> <input name="category_base" id="category_base" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $category_base ); ?>" class="regular-text code" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="tag_base"><?php _e('Tag base'); ?></label></th>
        <td><?php echo $blog_prefix; ?> <input name="tag_base" id="tag_base" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($tag_base); ?>" class="regular-text code" /></td>
    </tr>
    <?php do_settings_fields('permalink', 'optional'); ?>
</table>

<?php do_settings_sections('permalink'); ?>

<?php submit_button(); ?>
  </form>
<?php if ( !is_multisite() ) { ?>
<?php if ( $iis7_permalinks ) :
    if ( isset($_POST['submit']) && $permalink_structure && ! $using_index_permalinks && ! $writable ) :
        if ( file_exists($home_path . 'web.config') ) : ?>
<p><?php
    printf(
        /* translators: 1: web.config, 2: Codex URL, 3: CTRL + a, 4: element code */
        __( 'If your %1$s file was <a href="%2$s">writable</a>, we could do this automatically, but it isn&#8217;t so this is the url rewrite rule you should have in your %1$s file. Click in the field and press %3$s to select all. Then insert this rule inside of the %4$s element in %1$s file.' ),
        '<code>web.config</code>',
        __( 'https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions' ),
        '<kbd>CTRL + a</kbd>',
        '<code>/&lt;configuration&gt;/&lt;system.webServer&gt;/&lt;rewrite&gt;/&lt;rules&gt;</code>'
    );
?></p>
<form action="options-permalink.php" method="post">
<?php wp_nonce_field('update-permalink') ?>
    <p><textarea rows="9" class="large-text readonly" name="rules" id="rules" readonly="readonly"><?php echo esc_textarea( $wp_rewrite->iis7_url_rewrite_rules() ); ?></textarea></p>
</form>
<p><?php
    printf(
        /* translators: %s: web.config */
        __( 'If you temporarily make your %s file writable for us to generate rewrite rules automatically, do not forget to revert the permissions after rule has been saved.' ),
        '<code>web.config</code>'
    );
?></p>
        <?php else : ?>
<p><?php
    printf(
        /* translators: 1: Codex URL, 2: web.config, 3: CTRL + a */
        __( 'If the root directory of your site was <a href="%1$s">writable</a>, we could do this automatically, but it isn&#8217;t so this is the url rewrite rule you should have in your %2$s file. Create a new file, called %2$s in the root directory of your site. Click in the field and press %3$s to select all. Then insert this code into the %2$s file.' ),
        __( 'https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions' ),
        '<code>web.config</code>',
        '<kbd>CTRL + a</kbd>'
    );
?></p>
<form action="options-permalink.php" method="post">
<?php wp_nonce_field('update-permalink') ?>
    <p><textarea rows="18" class="large-text readonly" name="rules" id="rules" readonly="readonly"><?php echo esc_textarea( $wp_rewrite->iis7_url_rewrite_rules(true) ); ?></textarea></p>
</form>
<p><?php
    printf(
        /* translators: %s: web.config */
        __( 'If you temporarily make your site&#8217;s root directory writable for us to generate the %s file automatically, do not forget to revert the permissions after the file has been created.' ),
        '<code>web.config</code>'
    );
?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php elseif ( $is_nginx ) : ?>
    <p><?php _e( '<a href="https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx">Documentation on Nginx configuration</a>.' ); ?></p>
<?php else:
    if ( $permalink_structure && ! $using_index_permalinks && ! $writable && $update_required ) : ?>
<p><?php
    printf(
        /* translators: 1: .htaccess, 2: Codex URL, 3: CTRL + a */
        __( 'If your %1$s file was <a href="%2$s">writable</a>, we could do this automatically, but it isn&#8217;t so these are the mod_rewrite rules you should have in your %1$s file. Click in the field and press %3$s to select all.' ),
        '<code>.htaccess</code>',
        __( 'https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions' ),
        '<kbd>CTRL + a</kbd>'
    );
?></p>
<form action="options-permalink.php" method="post">
<?php wp_nonce_field('update-permalink') ?>
    <p><textarea rows="6" class="large-text readonly" name="rules" id="rules" readonly="readonly"><?php echo esc_textarea( $wp_rewrite->mod_rewrite_rules() ); ?></textarea></p>
</form>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php } // multisite ?>

</div>

<?php require( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-footer.php' ); ?>
```

I hope you can help me once again!

Comment: Just go to the database and search for old URL everywhere, replace the old one from new. Also check your files any hard-coded old URL and replace them also. Disable cache plugin if you are using any.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your config.php file, example.com is the new address you want your website accessible at

`define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');`

see here for more information
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the URLs in the db:

**Change Siteurl & Homeurl**

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'http://www.newsiteurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
```

**Change GUID**

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'http://www.newsiteurl.com');
```

**Change URL in Content**

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'http://www.newsiteurl.com');
```

**OR**
**Change Image Path Only**

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'src="http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'src="http://yourcdn.newsiteurl.com');
```

**and change attachement GUID too**

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET  guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'http://yourcdn.newsiteurl.com') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';
```

Your tables must have the `wp_` prefix otherwise change it with your in the queries)

YFinally you can refer to [this article](https://onextrapixel.com/13-useful-wordpress-sql-queries-you-wish-you-knew-earlier/) if you want, but there are millions of similar articles.